# How to display html file after the condition becomes true in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

How can I display html file when a certain condition gets true in javascript code.

**Javascript Code**

```
lest = ["heru", "firu"];
for (lul of lest) {
  if ("heru" === lul) {
    // show below html code when heru is in lest
  }
}
```

**Html code which I want to show when condition becomes true**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Random Background</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      #video-background {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="video-background" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <script>
      // Define an array of image sources
      const imageSources = [
        "4.webp",
        "5.jpg"
      ];
      
      // Define an array of video sources
      const videoSources = [
        "2.mp4",
        "3.mp4"
      ];
      
      // Select a random image or video source
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // 0 for image, 1 for video
      const source = randomIndex === 0 ? imageSources[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageSources.length)] : videoSources[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoSources.length)];
      
      // Set the background using the selected source
      if (randomIndex === 0) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${source})`;
      } else {
        const video = document.getElementById('video-background');
        video.querySelector('source[type="video/mp4"]').src = source;
        video.querySelector('source[type="video/webm"]').src = source.replace('.mp4', '.webm');
        video.load();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**I tried Doing this by creating content.js file and writing follwing code:**

```
 const landing = () => {
      return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Random Background</title>
            <style>
              body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100vh;
              }
              #video-background {
                position: fixed;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <video id="video-background" autoplay muted loop>
              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <script>
              // Define an array of image sources
              const imageSources = [
                "4.webp",
                "5.jpg"
              ];
              
              // Define an array of video sources
              const videoSources = [
                "2.mp4",
                "3.mp4"
              ];
              
              // Select a random image or video source
              const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // 0 for image, 1 for video
              const source = randomIndex === 0 ? imageSources[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageSources.length)] : videoSources[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoSources.length)];
              
              // Set the background using the selected source
              if (randomIndex === 0) {
                [document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${source})`;][1]
              } else {
                const video = document.getElementById('video-background');
                video.querySelector('source[type="video/mp4"]').src = source;
                video.querySelector('source[type="video/webm"]').src = source.replace('.mp4', '.webm');
                video.load();
              }
            </script>
          </body>
        </html>
    `;
    };
 lest = ["heru", "firu"];
    for (lul of lest) {
      if ("heru" === lul) {
        document.body.innerHTML = landing;
      }
    }
```

But Got error in `document.body.style.backgroundImage =` url(${source})`;` part as It can't include `  ` inside `  ` .

And getting error: `";" expected` at url and $ part. I am getting blank screen when this condition gets true. This code was for chrome extension.

I am getting  result when writing:

document.body.innerHTML = `<p> hello</p>`;

What could be possible solutions

Comment: having my doubts about this condition `if (heru === lul) {`  is `heru` a variable or shouldn't you compare `lul` with a string `"heru"`?

Comment: @ChrisG edited comparing lul with a string heru

Comment: try escaping the backticks ... ```backgroundImage = \`url(${source})\`;][1```

Comment: Instead of writing the HTML, why not navigate to a page that has that HTML?

Comment: @jsotola tried but showing blank screen instead of showing random images and videos

Comment: instead of document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${source})`; cant you do something like `document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+source+')';`